# Sveltekit run fine but when i try to create a build it throw error

Tags: sveltekit

I integrate `MultiSafepay` in `Sveltekit` it works fine but when I try to create a build it throws an error

> TypeError: MSPClient.default is not a constructor

My code is

```
import  MSPClient from '@multisafepay/api-wrapper';
export const client = new MSPClient(API_KEY);
```